# Array cannot access elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am playing with the amazon alexa skills and trying to write my own. I have an array for some elements of the skill, but I cannot access the elements. I believe I've done everything correctly and I've googled a fair bit, but nothing seems to be working?!

```
var myArray = [
    { "name" : "matt",    "content" : "this is about matt" },
    { "name" : "james",   "content" : "this is about james" },
];
```

I then have some code based on the user input which uses the name as a finder.

```
var requestedName = "matt";
var contentToRead = myArray.filter(function(v){ return v.name == requestedName; });
console.log("I'll read back, " + contentToRead.content);
```

The above console.log is coming back as undefined. I've tried to parse the results to an array, but nothing I try seems to work.

any ideas? I am sure it's something simple, but my knowledge isn't enough to actually know what specifically to look for to solve it!!

Comment: Use contentToRead[0].content instead of contentToRead.content

Answer (score 3):

`.filter` filters the array, it *removes values not matching the filter*; what you'll get back is still an array with multiple objects (because the predicate may apply to more than one value in the array).

The behaviour you want, returning the first match, is implemented in [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
var contentToRead = myArray.find(function (v) { return v.name == requestedName; });
```

Comment: Do note the compatibility of `.find`, it's not supported by all browser.

Comment: I think there could be more than one result with the same name.. If the filter is by a unique property or if the intention is to find the very first occurrence than there is no question that `find()` will be the best solution..

Comment: @Yosvel It seems obvious that the OP expects only one result to be returned… Arguably they should have an object mapping that unique name to the user object then, instead of an array.

Answer (score 2):

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the given function, so `contentToRead` is an array:

```js
var myArray = [
    { "name" : "matt",    "content" : "this is about matt" },
    { "name" : "james",   "content" : "this is about james" },
];

var requestedName = "matt";
var contentToRead = myArray.filter(function(v) { return v.name === requestedName; });
  
// You can loop over contentToRead array
contentToRead.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log("I'll read back, " + item.content);
});
```

Comment: Yes this one works too - thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

`filter` creates a new **array** containing the elements for which the function you pass it returns true.

`content` isn't a property of the **array**, it is a property of *each object inside that array*.

You would need need to get elements out of the array to read their content.

```
contentToRead.forEach(function (currentValue) {
    console.log("I'll read back, " + currentValue.content);
});
```

Comment: Nice! loved the explainition

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by `myArray.filter(function(v){ return v.name == requestedName; });`is an array containing the object matching your filter.
As you only have one object in it, you could access it like :

```
contentToRead[0].name
```